# A different Traveling Salesman problem

Tags: lateral-thinking

A salesman travelled due west from city A to city B. The distance he travelled was X km. He returned from B to A and found that he had travelled half the distance i.e. 1⁄2X. How can that be?

Comment: Are the cities considered "points" for this puzzle?  Can half of the first trip be done while still staying within the city limits of City A?

Comment: This seems far too broad to have one single answer, apart from a "guess the number I'm thinking of" right answer according to @amirul

Comment: Edges in TSP can have different weights. Or is this a planar TSP (one where distance is calculated by absolute difference of coordinates on 2D plane?

Answer (score 33):

Maybe

> A is two thirds of the way around the globe

so

> to return to B, the shortest path would be to continue the last third -- 1/2X

There are probably

> Lots of other tricks with a globe, e.g the salesman is near the north pole, for example.

Comment: Won't' exactly be 2/3 since the rotation of earth should also be taken into account.

Comment: Yeah it was also the first thing that has come to my mind, but why didn't he travelled on the short path(1⁄2X kms) instead of Xkm's in the first place?

Comment: No rotation would not have effect on the travel speed.

Comment: @BurakMete Well, since he travelled due west? So this is *plausible*

Comment: Right, makes sense

Comment: I wasn't saying it makes sense; if the OP hadn't specified that he travelled due west at the start then I probably would've had to find a good reason why he'd do that

Comment: @HerbWolfe If it was about time the rotation of the earth still has nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 23):

Simple:

> A and B are the same city. X=0km.

Comment: come on!! .....

Comment: or there at at an infinite distance from each other.

Comment: If x = 0, then x is a point and thus has no direction (as direction is determined by a change in position), so he couldn't have traveled due west in this scenario.

Comment: This is good lateral thinking!

Comment: Oh Jon, we need a non-trivial solution to this problem!

Answer (score 7):

> Both City A and City B are on the equator, City B was 28000km west of A, he went back going west as well, which would be 14000km.

Comment: Your answer is correct given the information but the OP should give time to travel too. Since the earth rotates and we travel relative to it.

Comment: It doesn't have to be on the equator

Comment: @Wen1now there's no absolute frame of reference, but there is the CMB stationary frame of reference (600 km/s relative to Earth, so not relevant here) and there's the inertial frame of reference comoving with Earth. But then again "due west" is only defined in frames of reference in which the surface of Earth is relatively stationary.

Comment: @somebody with the distances i stated, it needs to be :P

Comment: @DrunkWolf well it doesn't need to be those distances does it :P (tbh those distances are really far as well)

Comment: @somebody I know it doesn't need to be those distances, but on the equator, they do need to be :P Since the question is lateral-thinking, I don't believe he was searching for an exhaustive list of possible solutions, just a collection of correct answers. This was mine.

Answer (score 6):

> He traveled through mountain curvy roads, seasides etc...

and after that

> he turned back by plane by (almost) straight line

Comment: Well, then he wouldn't be travelling due west

Comment: Hmm, I considered word 'due west' only to be applicable to the first sentence...

Comment: @mpasko256 The first sentence is the travel from A to B. You described that part as "He traveled through mountain curvy roads, seasides etc..."

Comment: Using a similar logic then maybe they were launched out of a cannon or went over a mountain such that their path was roughly an arc or curve with a length of X but the path on the ground was 1/2X.  This would allow the cardinal direction to be due West even though the actual path goes "around".  Clever answer!

Comment: @boboquack Can't you travel 'due west' in a zigzag? With how the question is formulated this is a good answer.

Answer (score 5):

While he travaled due west to get there, while returning, he

> followed the Geodesic.

Although I am not sure if that can make up for 50%.

Comment: If you're only allowed to travel less than 180 degrees in longitude, even close to a pole, the ratio between distances between a constant latitude path and a geodesic path is at most $\pi/2$. But the first path is allowed to go over 180 degrees in longitude, then it's clearly possible in any latitude (even in equator, see other answers).

Answer (score 3):

At least one of the cities could have moved.

This could be easily true with a 'tent city' or cities on different planets. For a space trip 'due west' could be a course tangential to the surface.

Comment: If a city moved do you still 'return' to it?

Answer (score 3):

He went straight over a mountain the first time, and though it's tunnel on the way back.

Answer (score 1):

He HAD in fact travelled half the distance (1/2X). Then he had travelled half the distance again (12/X), and got back to where he started (After a total distance of X).

You could even read the story as being told out of order, if that makes more sense.

Comment: I'm confused...

Comment: @maxathousand "He returned from B to A and found that he had travelled half the distance" Nowhere does it say he only travelled that distance, and no more than that. He had indeed travelled that. Twice.

Comment: That's the same as saying that you hold 3 apples while you are holding 6 of them.

Comment: @WeckarE. So by that logic, all of my friends are 2 years old.

Comment: @Geliormth Technically you are. Lateral thinking, right?

Comment: @maxathousand No, but they have lived for two years.

Comment: @WeckarE. You said "...they *have* lived..." but OP said "...you *had* travelled...". This is a subtle [but distinct](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/has-vs-had/) difference. Using the past perfect form "had travelled" means that, at the moment at which you "returned from B to A," you had completed the action of traveling.

Answer (score 1):

The frame of reference for measuring the distances is the Solar System. Taking into account rotation of the Earth and its orbit of the Sun, journey A-B started and concluded at fixed points in the Solar System that were twice the straight-line separation of those of journey B-A; because journey A-B took roughly twice the duration.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe

> City A is on a hill. He traveled a longer route going downhill because going down to steeply is harder/too dangerous, but on the way back he just took the most direct route.

Comment: A small problem - he wouldn't have travelled due west. By the way, welcome to Puzzling! Why don't you take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Answer (score 1):

This saleman was

> on a boat and had to go against the river to go, and let the water do the job on returning?